# 2 tables with more than one relationship

Tags: database-design

I have 2 tables, an events and users. These 2 tables has 2 types of relationship.

> 1 event can have 1 creator (user)
>   1 user can create many events

and

> 1 event can have many members (users)
>   1 user can join many events

for the many-to-many relationship, I will create another table to link them. Probably named it `participants`.

But I'm not sure how should I put my first relationship (1-to-N above) into this. How should I design it?

Comment: It's not one-to-one.. it's many to one. An event can have only one creator but a creator can create more than one event.

Comment: thanks @steph, I will fix this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creator is not related to your `participants`, so I would not try to mix them.

Add the reference to the creator as another column to the `event`.

Comment: is there any draw back on this? because it's kind of weird relationship for me :)

Comment: @Phelios: Not really, since these are two different types of relations. The creator might or might not be a participant of the event, this should not make a difference for your model. This extra column makes it easy to understand the relationships.

Answer (score 2):

`EVENTS` should have a field named `creator` (foreign key of `USERS`)

`USERS` joins `EVENTS` in a M-N relation named `PARTICIPANTS` as you said.

Comment: is there any draw back on this? because it's kind of weird relationship for me :)

Comment: No, it's perfectly normal ;) you just use the same "entity" for two different purposes, but there's nothing strange ^^. Building an other entity just for the creators would be a design error imho